# exporting procedural landscape

Tags: export, gltf

hi guys sorry if this is a repeat question but I haven't found the answer and I've been trying for days this is driving me nuts. So I am new to blender and I have created a procedural landscape and would like to export (.glb format) it so I can import it to three.js. When I export simple objects aka a cube with a texture everything works fine but when I try to export my landscape I get a plane with no textures. I am obviously missing a step or two that I should be doing before I export. If you need more info let me know.

Comment: i would really appreciate some help on this should i be creating a landscape a different way such as ANT

Comment: When you say "procedural landscape" did you use a displacement modifier? or use shader nodes connected to the displacement socket?

Comment: I've done both using a noise texture in the displacement node and baking the image then using it with the displacement modifier in both cases when I export i get a plane with no displacement or materials

Answer (score 1):

Using node based shaders and modifiers is something that is specific to blender, neither of these export well to other programs.

For node based materials, you can bake the shader nodes to an image that can be used in other programs. This only applies to the surface appearance; such as colour, specularity, glossiness...

A normal map used in a shader can also be used in other programs, but mesh displacement in shaders **will not** export.

When you are using a displacement modifier, as well as any modifier except armature, you will need to apply the result of the modifiers when exporting. Most exporters provide an option to do this for you during export. For gltf, look for the Apply Modifiers option, in 2.80 it is under General, in 2.81 it is under Geometry.